# App Engine SDK: How do I view keys in a specific namespace using the Memcache Viewer?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, memcached

I'm trying to use the Memcache Viewer in the App Engine Dev Console to view keys in a specific namespace. The obvious syntax of namespace.key is not working; I haven't been able to find documentation describing specific usage. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible. In dev, check namespace'd memcache items programmatically, e.g. using a handler.

Credit: moraes on #appengine / freenode (validated by looking at source)